# Deleting items in NSCollectionView throws error

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

Good day,

I have an NSCollectionView which requires a lot of adding and delete. I have a function that adds to the end of the NSCollectionView perfectly and that is working effectively but my function to delete items in the NSCollectionView works sometimes but other times it throws an error below is the error

```
Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
2021-02-19 09:08:34.718073+0100 Kokoca[33243:2652479] Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
```

Ive saved a user default to tell me which section and item the user is deleting. I've made it so that the user cannot delete the first item due to it being very essential but when I try to delete other items it works sometimes until it crashes when I keep trying to delete more items. I'm not very familiar with collectionViews so any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. Below is my code:

```
    
    @objc func deleteview() {
        var newSearch = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "DeletedTab")
        let newSection = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "DeletedSection")
        if newSearch == 0 {
            return
        }
        else {
            self.theTabList.remove(at: newSearch)
            print(newSearch)
            print(newSection)
            var set: Set<IndexPath> = [IndexPath(item: newSearch, section: newSection)]
            tabCollectionView.deleteItems(at: set)
            theViewList.remove(at: newSearch)
            theViewList[newSearch].removeFromSuperview()
            var defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            var theCurrentTab = tabCollectionView.item(at: IndexPath(item: theTabList.count - 1, section: 0)) as! TabItem
            theCurrentTab.isSelected = true
            print("TheTabList: " + String(theTabList.count))
            print(theTabList)
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why its buggy? would appreciate it.

Comment: You are not updating the collection view.

Comment: I should call the reload data function of the collectionView?

Comment: @ElTomato I've tried reloading the data

Comment: What are `theViewList.remove(at: newSearch)` and `theViewList[newSearch].removeFromSuperview()` doing?

Comment: @Willeke its meant to remove a view at that index and remove it from its superview

Comment: @Willeke Just remove that piece of code and I found out that was the issue, I think I have to figure out another way of doing that. Thank you

Comment: Use `theViewList[newSearch]` before `theViewList.remove(at: newSearch)`.

Comment: @Willeke  THANK YOU BROO, JUST REALISED THAT. Appreciate it